# OCaml data members without initialization

Tags: oop, ocaml, data-members

I would like to create an object with a data member using OCaml but do not necessarily want to specify an initial value for the data member. Many examples seem to use a list but I would like to use a single instance of an object type I've created. Is this possible? Thanks.

```
class bar = object end;;

class foo =
object (self)
val myDataMember = ((* ??? *) : bar)
end;;
```

Additionally, I've tried the option keyword to no avail:

```
class bar = 
object (self) 
    method doIt = Printf.printf "Doing it!"
end;;

class foo bar =
object (self)
  val mutable myDataMember = (None : bar option)
  method get = myDataMember
end;;

let f = new foo (new bar);;
f#get#bar#doIt;;
```

Here, the compiler complains about the data member having "bar option" type when I wished to specify it to have bar type.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use optional type:

```
class foo =
object (self)
val myDataMember = (None : bar option)
end;;
```

of course, for this to be usable you will probably have to use mutable:

```
class foo =
object (self)
  val mutable myDataMember = (None : bar option)
  method set t = myDataMember <- (Some t)
  method get () =
    match myDataMember with
    Some x -> x
    None -> failwith "not initialized"
end;;
```

Comment: I seem to have trouble with the result when using the option keyword. I've updated the original post. Please help. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 1):

> f#get#bar#doIt;;
>
> Here, the compiler complains about the
>   data member having "bar option" type
>   when I wished to specify it to have
>   bar type.

In response to your new question. You didn't specify it to be of type `bar`, you specified it to be of `bar option` (exactly when you typed `(None : bar option)`). To access this you need to match --this might be better in the `get` method, but the point is valid.

```
match f#get#bar with
  | Some x -> x#doIt
  | None -> failwith "value not initialized"
```

I don't know what you intended `bar` to mean when you wrote, `class foo bar`, but it's an argument for the class `foo` (functional object) and has nothing to do with the class `bar`. Take a look at the type definition of `foo`.

```
'a -> object val mutable data : bar option method get : bar option end
```

This is an object that takes one argument, of any type and constructs an instance of the object. Overall, I don't think you want an option type as a solution, but leverage functional objects, like this:

```
class bar = object (self)
    method doIt = Printf.printf "Doing it"
end

class foo (arg1:bar) = object (self)
    val mutable data = arg1
    method get = data
    method set new_data = data <- new_data
end
```